# Installing sSMTP from SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, rpm, ssmtp

I'm on a Web Hosting Buzz reseller account. They have some very stringent mail sending rules, including blocking of authenticated SMTP socket mail sending using PEAR. It was suggested in WHB forum that this was possible with sSMTP. I've since gotten SSH access and googled how to install sSMTP from SSH:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
yum install ssmtp
```

However, the first line fails with:

```
Retrieving http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
error: skipping http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
```

It was a very old thread in WHB forum and the thread poster could not be reached for assistance. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

use 
`rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 1):

sSMTP is alternative to Sendmail. sSMTP is a send-only sendmail emulator for machines which normally pick their mail up from a centralized mailhub (viapop, imap, nfs mounts or other means).

Download & Install:

```
# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
# yum -y install ssmtp
```

Read more on my site: http://www.techgyaan.org/2011/09/how-to-install-and-configure-ssmtp-on-html/